# AS400 thousand delimiter on numeric field

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, number-formatting, decimalformat

Is there a way to get a number formatted with a comma for thousand in numbers?

According to IBM documentation, this is the syntax:

```
DECIMAL(:newsalary, 9, 2, ',')
```

newsalary is the string (field)
9 is the precision
2 is the scale
, is the delimiter.

I tried:

```
SELECT DECIMAL ( T1.FIELD1 , 15 , 2 , "," ) AS TOTAL FROM TABLE T1
```

When trying it, I am getting the following error:

> Message: [SQL0171] Argument 4 of function DECIMAL not valid.

Comment: Is t1.field1 decimal or string?

Comment: I found the example you are relying on, and it won't work for your case. Its used to replace ',' with '.' E.G. 1020,50 to 1020.50 , what I'd suggest for you is substring the first 3 letters and then concat with a comma, then substring 4-6 and concat with comma and so on.

Comment: If t1.field1 is a string, then it already has a comma in it, according to how you're trying to use DECIMAL(). The function expects to remove the comma so that it can create a valid numeric value (which cannot have embedded commas). What exactly are you intending to do with the resulting value (once it's numeric)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECIMAL converts from string type to a numeric type.

Numeric types don't have separators; only character representations of numbers have separators.

What tool are you using STRSQL, Run SQL Scripts or something else?  Once you convert the string to a number, the tool should add the language appropriate separators when it displays the numeric data.   For example, in STRSQL:

```
select decimal('12345.67', 12,2) as mynum
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Returns:

```
       MYNUM
   12,345.67
```

Using SQL to format strings is usually a bad idea.  That should be left to whatever is consuming the data.

But if you really, really, really want to do it.  You should create a user defined function (UDF) that does it for you.  Here's an article, [Make SQL Edit the Way You Want It To](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg121510-story01.html) that includes source for for an EDITDEC function  written in ILE RPG along with the SQL function definition you need to use it in an SQL statement.